# Date Dimension line chart on Google data Studio showing null values (even with filters)

Tags: looker-studio

Dears, please help with this issue, i tried everything on my reach, filters wont work, I cant make it ignore future weeks with null data:

[image: my data image]

How do i get rid of that blank space?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697) chart, it can be achieved by setting the *X-Axis Date Range* to **Range by Data**.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/9e719dbc-2e41-4aad-8205-f28880bfe979) to demonstrate, as well as a GIF showing the process:

[image: 3]]